# Using C# code to set internet options

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, registry

I don't want to choose Tools->Internet Options->Connections->LAN Settings->Automatic configuration->Automatically detect settings so that I can visit webpages faster when using a HTTP client.

How can I do this with C# code in Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4?

Comment: I think you can do this using an registry hack

Comment: I don't know if that would work unless Freddie continuously monitors for changes. There is a c++ structure that returns proxy changes, requiring pinvoke and such in c#.